# network programming in python

Tags: python

how do i run a python program that is received by a client from server without writing it into a new python file?

Comment: I'm curious to know why you need to do that. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

```
code = "for a in range(10):\n\tprint 'lol'\n"
eval(compile(code, 'downloaded_code_fake_filename', 'exec'))
```

but Beware of Security Issues ! The source code should be  cryptographically signed and not transmitted in plaintext.

Comment: code = "for a in range(10):\n\tprint 'lol'\n"
eval(compile(code, 'downloaded_code_fake_filename', 'exec'))
didn't understand it. could you explain a bit?

Comment: @Ani: In his answer @BatchyX has given an example of how to execute the code you'd receive from a client. `code` is a sample code snippet; copy it to IDLE and `print` it to see what it looks like. `eval` is a built in function that evaluates the code snippet assigned to the `code` variable. See the docs: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval

Comment: is the exec function deprecated? Couldn't he just `exec(code)`?

Comment: Do we have to do something extra in case there are functions in the program that we are trying to execute through eval() ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [execnet](http://codespeak.net/execnet/). It's well supported and from what I've read much safer than a raw exec or eval. For what you're trying to do check out the [basic examples](http://codespeak.net/execnet/example/test_info.html).

Comment: shiny! and an interesting and useful way to do distributed/agent processing in python.

Answer (score 0):

see http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#exec for the `exec()` function. it is not deprecated in py3.1. i recommend doing simply `exec(code)`. values can be passed by inspecting variables in either the globals or locals dictionary:

```
code = """
def f(): return 42
R = f()
"""
d = {}
exec( code, d )
print( d[ 'R' ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Dcolish's answer is good. I'm not sure the idea of executing code that comes in on a network interface is good in itself, though - you will need to take care to verify that you can trust the sending party, especially if this interface is going to be exposed to the Internet or really any production network.